# Unable to access external HD using Chromium

Tags: chromium, external-hdd

New to using Ubuntu for desktop - just made the switch Thursday evening in fact.  Running an AMD system - Phenom II processor, standard 500gB HD, 8gB RAM.

I cannot access my Seagate external HD through Chromium at all.  I can through Firefox, but as I do have a G+ account along with a private group I manage on there, I need to be able to access it with Chromium as well.

For example, through Facebook or G+ on Chromium, if I attempted to upload a photo to a post using the photo/video on FB or attach file on G+, my external hard drive was no where to be seen.  It was like it wasn't even mounted.  However, if I used Firefox as my browser, with Facebook, I could see my external HD listed right below 'computer' in the 'other places' tab in the folders dialog box.  Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology, as I'm brand-new to using a Linux OS as I stated.

I have spent the last three days trying to find a solution, and nothing is matching my specific problem.  The external shows on everything except Chromium.

Anyone out there know a fix for this?

Comment: You're going to need to [edit] your question and be a bit more specific about what errors your getting, how exactly you're trying to access the disk, etc… What you've posted so far provides no information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: I edited.  Added all the details, as well as the solution I found.  I find it a bit rude to downvote someone for asking for help when they state they're new, though.

Comment: Please add solutions to the answers section below.

Comment: I have removed the solution part from the question. But you can find it [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1017077/2). Please post the solution part in the "Your Answer" field below. It's completely okay to answer your own question and accept your answer.

Comment: With Chromium you should be able to navigate to `/media/youruser/`. Can you confirm?

Comment: @JadeAutumn Please [edit] your post to include the [information requested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017077/unable-to-access-external-hd-using-chromium#comment1650429_1017077) as that is the best strategy to follow in order to obtain a quality answer, and also improves the quality of the question. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Yes, I could navigate to /media/myname/.  But the Seagate did not show whatsoever.  I'm not sure what words I'm not using to not make this any clearer, but after the first day on here when I was downvoted for asking for help and then the first response which I felt was harsh, I won't be asking in here again.

Comment: @Jade firstly, we cannot know who downvoted you, or why. I am one guy who finds downvotes without comments quite difficult to understand, but they might happen. I have been downvoted sometimes, mods and staff have been downvoted sometimes, it just happens. It is also easy to feel a bit attacked by these actions but the truth is the point is helping and getting help, not reaching high scores. You should not even bother about the occasional downvote and still feel free to come here and ask something anytime you need, as long as it's about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

A Linux user from another group suggested downloading Chrome and trying that.  Through Chrome, I was able to navigate to my external HD and access all the files.  With Chromium, the external HD never showed up in my navigation folder whatsoever.

So the solution is to just install Chrome.